# Find values of a and b

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am required to find numbers a and b so that:
$$\frac{2x+5}{x^2+x-6}=\frac{a}{x+3}+\frac{b}{x-2}$$

$$\frac{ax-2a\:+\:bx+3b}{x^2+x-6}$$

$$\therefore ax-2a\:+\:bx+3b\:=\:2x+5 $$

To this step i understand my process and the rest i believe would be like a simultaneous equation, or I could even use a trial and error method to find the numbers, but I know there is a much simpler way to solve this, what step is next? or have I made a mistake?

Comment: You have a typo here: $ax\color{red}{+}2a$. It is called partial fraction decomposition. See Example 1 here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: @farruhota thanks i fixed them

Comment: Sorry, it was the other part: $x\color{red}{-}2$. I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the most basic method. Group the $x$ coefficients
$$ (a+b)x + (3b-2a) = 2x + 5 $$

this needs to be true for $\forall x \in \mathbb R$. Therefore

$$ a + b = 2 $$
$$ 3b - 2a = 5 $$

Solve this system for $a,b$

Comment: Can you please explain your process as I am having trouble understanding how you came to a + b = 2 and 3b - 2a = 5

Comment: @Utsav if $Ax + B = Cx + D$ must hold for all $x$, then $A = C$ and $B=D$, hence the equations.

Comment: The coefficients in $x$ must be equal on both sides

Answer (score 4):

$$x^2+x-6=(x+3)(x-2)$$

We have $$a(x-2)+b(x+3)=2x+5$$

Set $x-2=0$ and $x+3=0$ one by one

Comment: Can you please explain why you set x + 2 and x + 3 equal to 0? I do not understand that

Comment: @Utsav, Sorry for the typo. If we set $x-2=0,$ the coefficient of $a$ becomes zero, right?

Comment: yes but how can we just decide to make x - 2 = 0? if we do this, dont we have to do the same to the other side?

Comment: @Utsav - that's exactly what you do - you make $x-2=0$ - that is, make $x=2$. If you let $x=2$, then the equation becomes $5b=9$, easy to solve for $b$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x=0$ to get $\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}=\frac{-5}{6}$ and $x=-1$ to get $\frac{a}{2}+b=\frac{-1}{2}$ and solve them to get $a=-7, b=3$

Comment: There may be many values of a and b. How can you say there is only one value satisfying the equation.

Comment: It is a question of partial fractions and only unique answer exists

Comment: Ooops. Didn't notice this. thanks.

Comment: @LoveInvariants  you are welcome

Comment: Those are the values for $a$ and $b$.... when $x=0$. What about generally speaking?

Comment: It is general only we took $x=0,&x=-1$ for our convenience you can check it for any value it will be exactly same

Comment: @abhishekchaudhary ah yes I skipped over the $x=-1$ part. I know it now works, simply because of how graphs are constructed. Thanks for the clarification, though :)

Comment: @user477343 MSE is for clarification only and btw you are welcome